# LEMMA :: The pipeline needs to include a tagger in order to use Matcher or PhraseMatcher

Tags: python, nlp, google-colaboratory, spacy, lemmatization

when im trying to add a LEMMA to the pattern ;ends up getting this error::

The pipeline needs to include a tagger in order to use Matcher or PhraseMatcher with the attributes POS, TAG, or LEMMA. Try using nlp() instead of nlp.make_doc() or list(nlp.pipe()) instead of list(nlp.tokenizer.pipe()).

i was trying to run the code in colab

#code:

```
 import spacy
    from spacy.matcher import Matcher
    from spacy.lang.en import English

    nlp = English()

    npl=spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
    matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)
    pattern12 = [
          {"LEMMA": "love","POS":"VERB"},
        {"POS": "NOUN"}
    ]
    matcher.add("UNIL_LOVE",None,pattern12)
    doc3 = nlp("I loved dogs but now I love cats more.")

    matches = matcher(doc3)
    for match_id, start, end in matches:
        string_id = nlp.vocab.strings[match_id]  
        span = doc3[start:end] 
     print(match_id, string_id, start, end, span.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in your code. Change

```
nlp = English()
npl=spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
```

To:

```
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
```

Due to the typo, the nlp object does not have a tagger, thus the error.